# What is the name of the pattern where you set state data before async calls finish?

Tags: usability, design-patterns

So the aforementioned pattern would be something like this:

- User submits form
- Page immediately updates to show new entered data, with no page loader or wait time
- If there is a problem with the async api call, the state is reverted and an error message is then shown

I swear that I have seen a pattern with this name but I am drawing a total blank.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's called, but it seems like a flawed pattern. There's no transparency to the user as to when it saves successfully. Also, if I submit the form, it shows everything the way I entered it, then I close the page, there's no way for me to know there were any errors. Again, I don't know what it's called, but I'd describe it as "opaque" or "fragile".

Comment: It's really going to depend on the use case and is not meant for every call. I've seen this sort of pattern in play in Google apps. Essentially, it's just setting the local state so as to not block the user. It seems popular with progressive web apps or "offline" type of situations.

Comment: Hm.. Yeah, perhaps with non-critical calls it could be alright. Unfortunately, to your question, I can't offer any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known as an ***Optimistic UI***.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly it. Thank you! For posterity, I'll toss this article link/explanation in: https://uxplanet.org/optimistic-1000-34d9eefe4c05.